# Get current column of WPF Data Grid when button inside HeaderTemplate is clicked

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I Have a DataGrid with custom headers using a DataTemplate.

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="headerTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ParameterType}"/>
        <Button>Click</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Code:

```
DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn
{
    Header = new DataGroupParameter() 
    { 
        Name = "Parameter Name", 
        ParameterType = DataParameterType.Text 
    },
    HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("headerTemplate"),
    Binding = binding
};
myDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
```

How can I get the current column when the button inside the header template is clicked?

Thanks

Comment: What is `Name` bound to? Usually the `DataContext` of a header is the string that is the header text. Can you show how the template is used in your `DataGrid`?